# SharePoint: how to get Internet media type of a document?

Tags: sharepoint, soap, mime-types

How to get [Internet media type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) of a document using SharePoint web-services? I access the service using SOAP. I've tried the [Content Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms479905%28v=office.14%29.aspx) documentation, but it is something different than Conten-type/Internet media-type/MIME.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SharePoint doesn't know about MIME-types. At least it doesn't know this on a per-file basis.

Check out [`SPFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile_members.aspx) which represents a file in SharePoint. The closest you might get is [`SPFile.ProgID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.progid.aspx): *"Gets a string that identifies the application in which the file was created."*, but that doesn't correspond to the MIME-type and nor is it always filled.

The MIME types are actually assigned by the **IIS web server** as you can see in this explanation:

- [Add new file type in SharePoint](http://kerseub.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/add-new-file-type-in-sharepoint/)

[image]

So you will not be able to get the mime type by querying the SOAP web service. Your only chance is to download the file in question and check the **HTTP Header** in which you should find the `Content-Type` assigned by the IIS.

You won't be able to query by content type or similar stuff, you will have to use file extensions for that (e.g. xlsx, docx) - the IIS does nothing differently, it assigns the MIME-types by file extension. So instead of trying to get the mime-type, it might be easier to just get the file extension and deduct the mime-type from there.

Lastly: The SharePoint Content Type is a SharePoint internal construct. It represent different types of content in SharePoint, not always relating to downloadable documents. It has nothing to do with mime-types.

Comment: I see no more answers to this question, and I consider this answer as the most close to what I need, so I checked it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

In case of server-side code you may use:
`SPUtility.GetMimeTypeFromExtension(".pdf")`